# Let $X\sim U([0,1])$ and $Y|X ∼ Bin(X, n)$. Find the distribution of $Y$, leaving your answer in terms of the Beta function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve it, and I am getting that $\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\frac{1}{n+1}$, so $Y$ is $\mathbb{U}(0,n)$ (discrete uniform distribution).

I am not sure if my final make sense

Comment: It's correct, however $U(0,n)$ is used to mean uniform distribution on interval $(0,n)$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $Y$ takes value from $\{0,...,n\}$. For any $k \in \{0,...,n\}$ we have:

$$ \mathbb P(Y=k) = \mathbb E[ \mathbb P(Y=k | X)] = \mathbb E[{n \choose k} X^k (1-X)^{n-k}] = {n \choose k} \int_0^1 x^k (1-x)^{n-k}dx $$

The last one is equal to $$ {n \choose k}\mathcal B(k+1,n-k+1) $$
Where $\mathcal B$ is beta function.

It however can be evaluated to ${n \choose k} \frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(n-k+1)}{\Gamma(n+2)} = {n \choose k} \frac{k!(n-k)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n+1}$, so your result is correct, too.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Incomplete Beta, with $\int_{0}^{p}f_{Y}(Y=y|X=s)P(X=s)ds$?

Comment: No, note that $X \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ so the limits of integration should be $0$ and $1$. (and you probably wanted to write $\mathbb P(Y=y |X=s)f_X(s)ds$ )

Comment: Weird, then I get $P(X=k) = \int_{0}^{1}P(Y=k|X \leq p)P(X \leq p) dp = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{p}P(Y=k|X=s)f_X(s)ds dp$

Comment: How did you get your first equality?

Comment: Thank you @DominikKutek

Comment: So Y is uniformly distributed on {0,n} ? @DominikKutek

Comment: $Y$ is uniformly distributed on $\{0,1,...,n\}$, yes @SleimanBisharat